# traits ui variable number of mayavi scenes and visualization of run time traits

Tags: enthought, mayavi, traitsui

I would like to present the user with a variable number of scenes within the GUI (arranged say horizontally) composing different views of the data, depending on runtime conditions?

I really don't want to redefine the GUI, and a number of scene related traits for every use case. (i.e. bool_scene_1_viewable=Bool(), bool_scene_2_viewable=Bool()... )

It looks like I might be able to define a wildcard trait: scene_=Instance(Scene,()). But, if this is the best way to do it, how would I go about combining n traits into a View?

Answer (score 0):

(A) I did not distinguish between "runtime" dependence, and merely depending on some number of traits that are declared after initialization (but before config_traits is called). As such, I can use default_traits_view to create a view that depends on the current state of the object and its members.

(B) I was also confused about how to turn this list_of_scenes into an object that could be viewed. After all, HGroup and VGroup don't take lists! I was missing that * could be used to unpack the list.

Steps:
1. **init** class instance

```
foo=Foo()
```

2. add scenes as you like

> ```
> foo.add_trait(string_scene_name,scene)
> foo.scene_name_list.append(string_scene_name)
> foo.scene_list.append(scene)
> ```

3. Create group within default_traits_view()

> ```
> items=[Item(name,style='custom') for name in self. scene_name_list]
> scene_group=Group( *items)
> ```